# Stability of $\dot x=p(x)x$ for $p\in C^1 (\mathbb R)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Let $p\in C^1 (\mathbb R)$ and consider the differential equation $$\dot x=p(x)x.$$
>
> a) Show: If $p(0)>0$, then $0$ is unstable.
>
> b) Let $s>0$. Show: $s$ is asymptotically stable iff there is a $r>0$ such that $p$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. $p(x)>0$ for $s-r<x<s$
> 2. $p(x)<0$ for $s<x<s+r$

What I've got for a):

First of all we see that $0$ is a stationary point. Let $x_0$ be an initial point. Then, for $x_0>0$ any solution $\varphi$ will only take positive values (since otherwise there would be a $t'$ such that $\varphi (t')=0$ by the intermediate value theorem and then $\varphi'\equiv 0$ by Picard-Lindelöf since $p(x)x$ is continuous and therefor the solution unique, but $\varphi(0)=x_0>0$). Now, if we have $p(0)>0$, then on any neighbourhood $U_\varepsilon (0)$ we have $\dot\varphi >0$ and $0$ can't be asymptotically stable. Also it can't be lyapunov-stable since we can choose a neighbourhood $U_\epsilon(0)$ where $p(x)>0$ and thus $\varphi$ leaves the neighbourhood $U$.

For b):

It's quite visual what happens here: If we start at $0<x_0<s$ any solution $\varphi$ always stays in between $[0,s]$ for the reason mentioned above and if $s$ is asymptotically stable there is a neighbourhood $U_\epsilon(s)$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)=s$ on that neighbourhood. The problem though is that this doesn't necessarily mean $\dot\varphi>0$ on that neighbourhood so I could choose $r=\epsilon$. Or does it? How do I write that down mathematically accurate?

Edit: I think the converse of b) can be proven easily: If there is an $r>0$ such that $p(x)>0$ on $(s-r, r)$ and we start at some $x_0\in (s-r,r)$, then $\dot\varphi >0$ since $p(x)x>0$. So $\varphi$ is strictly monotonous, but also bounded because of $0<\varphi <s$ so we get $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)=s$ and thus $s$ is asymptotically stable. Note that $\varphi$ always stays in $[x_0,s)$, so $s$ also must be liapunov-stable.

Comment: The idea is (almost) perfect, but in its realization there appear some difficulties I do not know if you are aware of. For example, you write "and thus $\varphi$ leaves the neighbourhood". In fact, it has to remain in the open set where $p$ is positive (otherwise, that would contradict the uniqueness). So, you should take some neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that its closure is contained in the set of those $x$ for which $p(x)\ne0$ (plus $0$). Let $U=(a,b)$. Take any $x_0>0$, $x_0<b$. Let $M$ be defined as the infimum of $\{p(x)x:x\in[x_0,b]\}>0$.

Comment: Now, we have that $\varphi(t)\ge b$ for any $t\ge\frac{b-x_0}{M}$ for which $\varphi$ is defined (notice that $M$ is the minimum velocity between $x_0$ and $b$). Since $x_0$ can be taken as close to $0$ as we wish, we have obtained the Lyapunov instabilty from the right. And a proof of the instability from the left is analogous.

Comment: Okay, I see. And can you say something about b)?

Comment: For instance, assume that $0$ is an equilibrium and that $p(x)<0$ for $x\in(0, A)$. If you take $x_0\in(0,A)$ then $\varphi$ is (strictly decreasing). As it cannot reach $0$ (by uniqueness), it bounded below, so it has a limit $a\in [0,x_0)$. Suppose to the contrary that $a>0$. As earlier, let $M$ stand for the infimum of $\{-p(x)x:x\in[a,x_0]\}>0$. Then $\varphi$ attains the value $a$ in time not longer than $\frac{x_0-a}{M}$, a contradiction. Those arguments are typical of the **mathematical folklore**: everyone knows them, but it is hard to find them written down.